# How to set export table query with Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've created a script to export my BigQuery Data which comes from a Firebase Integration configuration. The manual script runs well but when I try to create it in python I am getting errors.

This is what I tried based on the configs I've seen in the manually created one

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

project_id = 'my_project_id'
dataset_id = 'analytics_000000000'
bucket_name = 'my_bucket'

sql = f"""
DECLARE tables ARRAY <STRING>;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.daily_export_log`
(
    table_name STRING,
    insert_date TIMESTAMP
);

SET tables = (SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(TABLE_NAME) TABLES
FROM
    `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(TABLE_NAME, 'events_\\\\d{{8}}') AND
    TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.daily_export_log`)
);


FOR tab IN 
    (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(tables))
DO
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    EXPORT DATA
    OPTIONS ( uri = CONCAT('gs://{bucket_name}/', ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''', '/*_', format_timestamp('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', current_timestamp()), '.json.gz'),
        format='JSON',
        compression='GZIP',
        overwrite=FALSE ) AS
    SELECT * FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` ''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    INSERT INTO `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.daily_export_log` SELECT ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''' table_name, current_timestamp() insert_date
    ''';
END FOR
"""

transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(
    destination_dataset_id="",
    display_name="BigQuery to GCS Daily Backup",
    data_source_id="scheduled_query",
    params={
        "query": sql
    },
    schedule="every 1 hours",
)

transfer_config = transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
    bigquery_datatransfer.CreateTransferConfigRequest(
        parent=f"projects/{project_id}",
        transfer_config=transfer_config,
        service_account_name=gccreds['client_email'],
    )
)

print("Created scheduled query '{}'".format(transfer_config.name))
```

When I try running that I get the below error.

```py
InvalidArgument: 400 Cannot create a transfer with parent projects/{project_id} without location info when destination dataset is not specified.
```

So I figured it's because of the line `destination_dataset_id=""` so I replaced it with `destination_dataset_id=dataset_id` which creates the job. However, when I check the status in BigQuery, it's failing with error:

```py
Error code 9 : Dataset specified in the query ('') is not consistent with Destination dataset '{dataset_id}'.
```

I've also tried including `dataset_region=location` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encounter this error since your query won't really be needing to write to a destination dataset but assigned value to `destination_dataset_id=dataset_id`. What you can do is remove parameter `destination_dataset_id` and in your `CreateTransferConfigRequest()` add **"location"** to `parent`. Your `parent` should look like this:

- `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}`

Edit the following on your code:

```
transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(
    display_name="BigQuery to GCS Daily Backup",
    data_source_id="scheduled_query",
    params={
        "query": sql
    },
    schedule="every 1 hours",
)

transfer_config = transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
    bigquery_datatransfer.CreateTransferConfigRequest(
        parent=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/us", # Just used 'us' as location for example. Just use your actual location so you won't encounter errors.
        transfer_config=transfer_config,
        service_account_name=gccreds['client_email'],
    )
)
```

Test run:
[image]

[image]

Query used for testing:

```
project_id = 'my-project-id'
dataset_id = 'test_dataset'
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'

sql = f"""
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://{bucket_name}/export/*.json.gz',
  format='JSON',
  compression='GZIP',
  overwrite=false
  ) AS
SELECT key,name FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.source_t`
"""
```

Comment: Excellent...it worked...thanks for the support...Was struggling with this for a while...just one thing to mention for other readers...I can't edit your answer but in the code snippet you are missing an 's' in 'location'...`parent=f"projects/{project_id}/location/us"` to `parent=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/us"`

Comment: @AndreiBudaes Thanks for pointing this out. I updated my answer.